# Not valid win32 application when creating RDOSession

Tags: outlook-redemption

new to this outlook.
basically trying to edit a draft mail's property and save it as a sent mail so i'm testing out using redemption. used the following code snippet but encountered error when creating the redeption object.

```
        RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = @"c:\SourceCode\Redemption\redemption64.dll";

        RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = @"c:\SourceCode\Redemption\redemption.dll";


        //Create a Redemption object and use it

        RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
enter code here

//error encounted : not a valid win32 application
```

Im using win64 with Outlook 64bit

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Could you please share your results here @DmitryStreblechenko ?

Comment: turns out it was a corrupted dll.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a corrupted dll.
i did a hash value check to verify it.
replaced the corrupted dll and it works perfectly.

Thanks all!